# Binary search on a priority_queue (efficient insert and search on a large list of strings)

Tags: c++11, priority-queue

I'm facing the problem of a holding a huge list of strings (~50k). Each string describes an already considered scenario. Thus, when a new scenario appears, it is discarded if its description is already in the list.

I was thinking that the obvious choice is to use a priority_queue of strings on which to perform a binary_search. (logarithmic insertion, logarithmic lookup).

Right?

Well, I can't find a way to do it using the standard C++ library.
Specifically, the priority_queue seems not to have .begin() .end()
methods to be given to the the binary_search() function.

Can't I use the standard library priority_queue+binary_search?
Then, what to use else?

Thanks !

**EDIT 1.**
Finally after several tests, I can confirm that the best choice for this problem (outperforming the others) is to use a set and its find method. This is:

```
set<string> consideredOptions; 
...
string newDescription = ....;
if ( consideredOptions.find(newDescription) == consideredOptions.end() ) {
  consideredOptions.insert(newDescription);
}
```

**EDIT 2.**
A priority_queue has a protected member named *c* that stands for the list of items. Then, it is easy to derive a new class with methods using *.begin()* and *.end()*.

```
class MyQueue : public std::priority_queue<std::string> {
 public:
  bool contains (const std::string & what) const {
    return std::find (c.begin(), c.end(), what) != c.end();  
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you think a priority_queue would be useful, rather than a sorted `vector`, or a `set`, or `unordered_set`? (You _could_ derive your own type from `priority_queue`, which would have access to the protected `c` member that exposes begin/end iterators ... but don't do that).

Comment: actually sounds like `map` or `unordered_map` is what you want (on second thought maybe just a `set`)

Comment: @Jonathan I thought on priority_queue so as not to perform sort() every time I insert just a single new string on a vector. priority_queue has a log inserting cost. And if pq is sorted, then a binary_search to find is optimal (log cost).

Comment: A `set` also has logarithmic insertions, and automatically does binary searches when you do lookups in it. You're over-complicating it, and that's not what priority queues are for. The standard library has loads of containers that do exactly what you want, priority queue is not one of them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, probably I'm over-complicating it. Then, I have to replace the pq by a set  Thanks.

Comment: Re Edit 1 `count` is simpler than `find`, but did you not read what I said about avoiding lookup+insert and just doing insert? Re Edit 2: `std::find` does a linear search, which is a terrible alternative!

Comment: @JonathanWakely. I think, for my case, find is better, cause an element is at most once in the set. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: So what? On a unique set count returns 1 or 0, i.e. true or false. There is no need to compare to the end iterator. But the important point is **avoid doing find + insert and just do insert**. I've said it four times now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, I can't find a way to do it using the standard C++ library.

You don't need a queue, you just need a collection where you can efficiently insert and do lookups. Use `std::unordered_set`. It has constant-time insertion and lookup.

A queue is used when you want to deal with things (and typically remove them from the queue) when they reach the "front" of the queue. From what you've described you don't need that. You only care whether things are in the collection or not, you don't care whether they are at the front or not.

With a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` you don't even need to bother doing the lookup, just try to insert each string. If it's already in the container then the return value will tell you the insertion failed. If it isn't in the container the return value tells you it wasn't there, but adds it in the same operation, which is twice as fast as doing a lookup and then doing an insertion.

```
unordered_set<string> consideredOptions; 
...
string newDescription = ....;
if ( consideredOptions.insert(newDescription).second ) {
  // newDescription was not in the set (but is now)
}
else {
  // newDescription was already considered
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that a search is optimal (log cost at much) in an "unordered" set?

Comment: It depends how many collisions you have, and the load factor of the container, but with a good hash function it is better than logarithmic. (Aside: why do you think searching is different to insertion? They have to do the same thing.)

Comment: @JonathatWakely Thanks. Compared set vs unordered_set and the latter outperforms the first.

Comment: After many trials, the right choice for my problem is not unordered_set. In fact this is incorrect: it fails to find strings positively in the set. The right choice is set + its find method (not the function binary_search).

Comment: Then you're using unordered_set wrong, if it couldn't find strings in the set it would be a serious bug in the implementation, and I doubt you've found such a bug (someone else would have noticed by now). The simplest way to check for an element's existence is not `find` but `count`. But read what I wrote above about not bothering to lookup, just inserting and seeing if it works. If you really care about performance then doing lookup+insert is foolish because it does twice as much work as needed.